# When I run my code I get (0, null) and cant figure out why

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am creating a program that is reading a file of names and ages then printing them out in ascending order. I am parsing through the file to figure out the number of name age pairs and then making my array that big. 
The input file looks like this:
(23, Matt)(2000, jack)(50, Sal)(47, Mark)(23, Will)(83200, Andrew)(23, Lee)(47, Andy)(47, Sam)(150, Dayton)

When I am running my code I get the output of (0,null) and I am not sure why. I have been trying to fix it for a while and am lost. If anyone can help that would be great My code is below.

```
public class ponySort {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int count = 0;
    int fileSize = 0;
    int[] ages;
    String [] names;
    String filename = "";
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(System.in);
    File file;
    do {
        System.out.println("File to read from:");
        filename = inputFile.nextLine();
        file = new File(filename);
        //inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    }
    while (!file.exists());
    inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    if (!inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println("No one is going to the Friendship is magic Party in Equestria.");
    }
    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String data1 = inputFile.nextLine();
        String[] parts1 = data1.split("(?<=\\))(?=\\()");
        for (String part : parts1) {
            String input1 = part.replaceAll("[()]", "");
            Integer.parseInt(input1.split(", ")[0]);
            fileSize++;
        }
    }
    ages = new int[fileSize];
    names = new String[fileSize];

    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = inputFile.nextLine();
        String[] parts = data.split("(?<=\\))(?=\\()");
        for (String part : parts) {
            String input = part.replaceAll("[()]", "");
            ages[count] = Integer.parseInt(input.split(", ")[0]);
            names[count] = input.split(", ")[1];
            count++;
        }
    }
    ponySort max = new ponySort();
    max.bubbleSort(ages, names, count);
    max.printArray(ages, names, count);
}
public void printArray(int ages[], String names[], int count) {
    System.out.print("(" + ages[0] + "," + names[0] + ")");
    // Checking for duplicates in ages. if it is the same ages as one that already was put in them it wont print.
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        if (ages[i] != ages[i - 1]) {
            System.out.print("(" + ages[i] + "," + names[i] + ")");
        }
    }
}
public void bubbleSort(int ages[], String names[], int count ){
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < count - i - 1; j++) {
            // age is greater so swaps age
            if (ages[j] > ages[j + 1]) {
                // swap the ages
                int temp = ages[j];
                ages[j] = ages[j + 1];
                ages[j + 1] = temp;
                // must also swap the names
                String tempName = names[j];
                names[j] = names[j + 1];
                names[j + 1] = tempName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

output example
File to read from:
file.txt
(0,null)
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: That’s a lot of code, using the debugger to find the bug is probably the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

What your code does is to Scan the file twice.
In the first loop you do

```
 String data1 = inputFile.nextLine();
```

Code reads first line and then scanner goes to the next (second) line.
Later you do again inputFile.nextLine(); The second line is empty and the code never goes into the second loop and content is never read.

If you can use Lists, you should create two array lists and add ages and names into the arraylists in the first scan, so you scan the file once. When done, you could get the Array out of the arraylist.

If you should only use arrays and you want a simple update, just add another Scanner before the second loop:

```
 ages = new int[fileSize];
 names = new String[fileSize];
 inputFile = new Scanner(file); // add this line
```

Comment: I have to have O (1) space in addition to the provided array would and array list be O(1)?

Comment: What do you mean by O(1)?